# How to get a jQuery click handler to fire when an attribute is checked programmatically?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, html-select, attr, checked

I have two DropDownLists that start off hidden:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    . . . other code elided for brevity

    $('[id$=ddlPayToIndividual]').hide();
    $('[id$=ddlPayToVendor]').hide();
});
```

...but one is shown based on which corresponding radio button is clicked:

```
$(document).on("click", '[id$=rbPaymentToIndividual]', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('[id$=ddlPayToVendor]').slideUp();
        $('[id$=ddlPayToIndividual]').slideDown();
    }
});

$(document).on("click", '[id$=rbPaymentToVendor]', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('[id$=ddlPayToIndividual]').slideUp();
        $('[id$=ddlPayToVendor]').slideDown();
    }
});
```

This all works when the user clicks either radio button (rbPaymentToIndividual or rbPaymentToVendor); however, when I programmatically check it:

```
$(document).on("click", '[id$=rbPaymentForSelf]', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        . . . other code elided for brevity
        $('[id$=rbPaymentToIndividual]').attr('checked', true);      
    }
});
```

...it doesn't. Why? Is there a workaround to get it to consider a programmatic attribute manipulation tantamount to a user's direct involvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried firing the click event?

`$('[id$=rbPaymentToIndividual]').prop("checked", true).click();`

Answer (score 1):

You can manually trigger a `change` event on the input:

```
$('[id$=rbPaymentToIndividual]').trigger('change');
```

as @tin points out - this is in addition to setting the property.

Comment: In addition to, or instead of, the attr('checked', true) ?

Comment: In addition to @B.ClayShannon. When you change the value of an element programmatically, they won't fire any events.